# Facebook Graph: Get likes for URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the facebook-graph API to get the current count of likes for a webpage. I tried this for a existing facebook-page:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMyExampleFacebookPage

it returns an JSON saying somewhere:
"likes": 123,
Fine so far.

So now I want to get the same for a non-facebook webpage like www.example.com. I tried:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com

and got:

```
"share": {
"comment_count": 31,
"share_count": 3038
},
```

... but no likes. How can I get the likes (not the share-count) for a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

since saturday 20th of june 2015, we cannot get the public_profile 
as you get with :

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com

Since Saturday we got :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Do you met this issue ?
Are we now all forced to use "User Access Token" , or "Page Access Token" ?

Comment: No, I used the Graph-Explorer and generated a temporary access-token. This allowes me to get an answer, but I only get "share_count", not "likes" - and I need the likes please.

Answer (score -2):

I used this, still working.

```
<?php 
$source_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOcO-DbJtQw";
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $likes = $xml->link_stat->like_count;
?>
```

Comment: _“still working”_ – yeah, but it might stop doing so at any point … all REST functionality has been deprecated by Facebook a long time ago already. Probably not the best idea to base any new implementation on that.

Comment: I second what @cbroe said

Comment: Thanks for all replys. So... hu... what is the way then? Or is there just no way to do it in an officical, non-deprecated manner?